# Usage and Impression of きない vs. こない

Tags: dialects

In Japanese class, we were always taught that the negative of 来{く}る is 来{こ}ない (not きない). In Japan, though, I've heard several native speakers use きない.
I have two questions about きない.

1. Who uses きない? People from rural areas? Rural Tohoku and Kanto regions? Is it part of a certain area's 方言?
2. What impression does きない give? One of my native Japanese friends got made fun of for using it, so I imagine きない is thought of as quaint or maybe uneducated by some. (Personally, I like it, though).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

そういえば…

When I was in Shikoku island, I remember some people used 「きない」, but that meant  「きなさい」 or 「きてください」, not 「こない」.

> はよう、こっち、きない！ (= はやく こちらに きなさい)

Seemingly this is used in [Fukuoka](http://fanblogs.jp/tomonariabc/archive/892/0) and [Oita](http://blog.livedoor.jp/kizunamise/archives/7658868.html), too.

I personally haven't heard きない which means こない, but I'm not familiar with dialects in Kanto region. *No impression* is my impression of that word.

Answer (score 4):

According to [here](http://komachi.yomiuri.co.jp/t/2010/1126/366694.htm) and [here](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BE%A4%E9%A6%AC%E5%BC%81), this is common in [茨城]{いばらき} and [群馬]{ぐんま}. Also appearing in Saitama and Chiba.

These were the top two links googling in きない 来ない...

Comment: Thanks for the information! I also heard someone from Miyagi using it, so it seems pretty widely used, but perhaps it's mainly a (rural-ish?) Kanto phenomenon?

Comment: I cannot recall ever hearing it in Tokyo. And no one uses it in Hokkaido. (but I should warn you that I'm not a native speaker of Japanese).

Comment: I've spent time living in Morioka up in Iwate prefecture, next in Utsunomiya in Tochigi prefecture, and lastly in Tokyo.  Any time I heard きない as a verb form, it was 着ない.  I never heard きない meaning 来ない.  Though similarly to virmaior, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Interesting! I've only ever heard it in Kanto (keeping in mind my stays in other areas have been relatively short); I would hear きない (as in 来ない) occasionally while living in Gunma. The only time I've heard it in Tokyo was from a non-Tokyo-ite (grew up in Miyagi Prefecture).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's a Western Kanto thing.

[http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/西関東方言#.E6.96.87.E6.B3.95](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A5%BF%E9%96%A2%E6%9D%B1%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80#.E6.96.87.E6.B3.95)

> 千葉県・埼玉県・群馬県・東京都多摩西部などで「こない」を「きない」や「きねー」と言ったりする。